# Linux 64-bit shellcode

Tags: assembly, nasm, shellcode

I'm trying to write my first "Hello world" shellcode on my Ubuntu 64-bit, but it doesn't work.

I have file **hello.asm**:

```
; 64-bit "Hello World!" in Linux NASM

global _start            ; global entry point export for ld

section .text
_start:

    ; sys_write(stdout, message, length)

    mov    rax, 1        ; sys_write
    mov    rdi, 1        ; stdout
    mov    rsi, message    ; message address
    mov    rdx, length    ; message string length
    syscall

    ; sys_exit(return_code)

    mov    rax, 60        ; sys_exit
    mov    rdi, 0        ; return 0 (success)
    syscall

section .data
    message: db 'Hello, world!',0x0A    ; message and newline
    length:    equ    $-message        ; NASM definition pseudo-instruction
```

I used this commands:

```
nasm -felf64 hello.asm -o hello.o
ld -o hello hello.o
objdump -d hello
```

I put shellcode from objdump into my C program:

```
char code[] = "\xb8\x01\x00\x00\x00\xbf\x01\x00\x00\x00\x48\xbe\xd8\x00\x60\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xba\x0e\x00\x00\x00\x0f\x05\xb8\x3c\x00\x00\x00\xbf\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0f\x05";

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int (*func)();
    func = (int (*)()) code;
    (int)(*func)();
    return 0;
}
```

and compile it in gcc, but after run I've got "Segmentation fault (core dumped)".

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. Assembler code seems to work, because when i run **./hello** it prints "Hello world".

Comment: `.data` section (where your code ends up) is not executable by default. Also, you should make sure your code is position independent.

Comment: On x86_64, are you sure this is valid: `length:  equ    $-message`

Answer (score 3):

It's good practice to remove nullbytes in case you want to inject it into a buffer, but main issue is probably that you have the string in the data segment?

I rewrote it like this and got it to work.

```
    global _start
    _start:
    jmp short string

    code:
    pop rsi
    xor rax, rax
    mov al, 1
    mov rdi, rax
    mov rdx, rdi
    add rdx, 14
    syscall

    xor rax, rax
    add rax, 60
    xor rdi, rdi
    syscall

    string:
    call code
    db  'Hello, world!',0x0A
```

---

```
$ nasm -felf64 hello.asm -o hello.o
$ ld -s -o hello hello.o
$ for i in $(objdump -d hello |grep "^ " |cut -f2); do echo -n '\x'$i; done; echo
\xeb\x1e\x5e\x48\x31\xc0\xb0\x01\x48\x89\xc7\x48\x89\xfa\x48\x83\xc2\x0e\x0f\x05\x48\x31\xc0\x48\x83\xc0\x3c\x48\x31\xff\x0f\x05\xe8\xdd\xff\xff\xff\x48\x65\x6c\x6c\x6f\x2c\x20\x77\x6f\x72\x6c\x64\x21\x0a
```

---

```
char code[] = "\xeb\x1e\x5e\x48\x31\xc0\xb0\x01\x48\x89\xc7\x4\x89\xfa  \x48\x83\xc2\x0e\x0f\x05\x48\x31\xc0\x48\x83\xc0\x3c\x48\x31\xff\x0f\x05\xe8\xdd\xff\xff\xff\x48\x65\x6c\x6c\x6f\x2c\x20\x77\x6f\x72\x6c\x64\x21\x0a";

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int (*func)();
    func = (int (*)()) code;
    (int)(*func)();
     return 0;
}
```

---

```
$ gcc -fno-stack-protector -z execstack -o code code.c    
$./code
Hello, world!
```

Comment: This is almost right, but not quite.  It should be `const char code[]` (then you don't need the `-fno-stack-protector -zexecstack`); and the `add rdx, 14` should be `add rdx, 12` to not write two past the end of the string.

Comment: Since the code is not in the stack, you don't need `-fno-stack-protector` but only `-z execstack`. Note that having executable data section as a result of `-z execstack` is a **Linux-specific behaviour**, described in details [here](http://blog.ioactive.com/2013/11/a-short-tale-about-executablestack-in.html). It does not work on FreeBSD, i.e. `-z execstack` leaves `.data` non-executable on that OS.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply, compile with `nasm -felf64` and link with `ld`. There is no need for `gcc`. I believe the issue you stumbled on was the `x86` style `equ    $-message` calculation in your code. For x86_64, that is not valid. Here is a quick example:

```
section .data
    string1 db  0xa, "  Hello StackOverflow!!!", 0xa, 0xa, 0

section .text
    global _start

    _start:
        ; calculate the length of string
        mov     rdi, string1        ; string1 to destination index
        xor     rcx, rcx            ; zero rcx
        not     rcx                 ; set rcx = -1
        xor     al,al               ; zero the al register (initialize to NUL)
        cld                         ; clear the direction flag
        repnz   scasb               ; get the string length (dec rcx through NUL)
        not     rcx                 ; rev all bits of negative results in absolute value
        dec     rcx                 ; -1 to skip the null-terminator, ecx contains length
        mov     rdx, rcx            ; put length in rdx
        ; write string to stdout
        mov     rsi, string1        ; string1 to source index
        mov     rax, 1              ; set write to command
        mov     rdi,rax             ; set destination index to rax (stdout)
        syscall                     ; call kernel

        ; exit
        xor     rdi,rdi             ; zero rdi (rdi hold return value)
        mov     rax, 0x3c           ; set syscall number to 60 (0x3c hex)
        syscall                     ; call kernel
```

**Compile/Output**

```
$ nasm -felf64 -o hello-stack_64.o hello-stack_64.asm
$ ld -o hello-stack_64 hello-stack_64.o
$ ./hello-stack_64

  Hello StackOverflow!!!
```

Comment: The issue is: (a) non-executable `.data` section; (b) absolute addressing in `mov rsi, message`. `equ $-message` works on x64 too.

Comment: Can you please explain to me what 0xa means in string1?

Comment: Sure `0xa` is just hexadecimal `10` which is the ASCII value for the `'\n'` (newline) character `:)`  (it's how you add newlines within a string)

Answer (score 0):

Hope is not too late to answer to this question :)

You must use this code to compile your C code (To disable stack protection and make it executable):

```
gcc -fno-stack-protector -z execstack -o hello hello.c
```

Good luck

Comment: The code is not on the stack but in the data segment, therefore your answer does not apply.

Comment: @HristoIliev I had written and executed my shellcode many times. It`s because of stack guard, not related to data segment. Please first test your idea and then leave a comment..

Comment: No, it is not because of stack guard. It is due to the non-executable `.data` section where the `code` symbol is located. `-z execstack` marks the `GNU_STACK` segment as executable which has the side effect of also making the data section executable. The code works fine without `-fno-stack-protector`. Also, making `code[]` `const` moves it from the `.data` section into the `.rodata` section and the latter is in the executable segment anyway, therefore `-z execstack` is not needed.

Comment: More technical explanation of why executable stack also makes the data section executable is to be found [here](http://blog.ioactive.com/2013/11/a-short-tale-about-executablestack-in.html). Note that this behaviour is specific to the Linux kernel and does not work on e.g. FreeBSD where having executable stack does not affect the default memory protection policy and `.data` remains non-executable.

Answer (score 0):

There's two layers of problem here.

1) `char data[] = ...` will be put in the data segment, which is not executable.  You need `const char data[] = ...` so that it is put in the text segment instead.  (Technically, it will be in the *read-only data* segment, which *could* be marked non-executable, but currently no one does that as far as I know.)

2) This is what I get when I disassemble the contents of `data`:

```
   0:   b8 01 00 00 00          mov    eax, 0x1
   5:   bf 01 00 00 00          mov    edi, 0x1
   a:   48 be d8 00 60 00 00    movabs rsi, 0x6000d8
  11:   00 00 00 
  14:   ba 0e 00 00 00          mov    edx, 0xe
  19:   0f 05                   syscall 
  1b:   b8 3c 00 00 00          mov    eax, 0x3c
  20:   bf 00 00 00 00          mov    edi, 0x0
  25:   0f 05                   syscall
```

and this is what I get when I try to run it:

```
$ strace ./a.out
execve("./a.out", ["./a.out"], [/* 38 vars */]) = 0
write(1, 0x6000d8, 14)                  = -1 EFAULT (Bad address)
_exit(0)                                = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

You can see that this is not *that* far off from what you wanted, but it clearly does not work, there being nothing at absolute address `0x6000d8`.  The problem is that you only put the *code* into `data`, not the string.  You need to put the string immediately after the code and use PC-relative addressing to get at it.  nighter's answer shows how that's done (under the additional constraint that no `\x00` bytes may appear in `data`, which would be necessary if you were actually exploiting a typical buffer overflow here instead of just goofing around with machine language).